# Eclipse Dali JPA Diagram Editor doesn't recognize entities within JAR

Tags: eclipse, jpa, editor, diagram, dali

Is it possible to Eclipse JPA Diagram Editor to read entities from a JAR?

I have configured the underlying persistence.xml (see below) with the JAR that contains the target entities. However, the Editor doesn't seem to see the entities.

However, when I link to the source file, the Editor works fine.

The persistence.xml with the JAR is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="com.saphir.modules.monitoring">
        <jar-file>module1.jar</jar-file>
        <jar-file>module2.jar</jar-file>
        <jar-file>module3.jar</jar-file>
        <jar-file>module4.jar</jar-file>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```